# Which frontend framework is the most Solidity/Ethereum friendly?

Tags: frontend, framework, rails

I'm coming from 10 years of freelance work using Rails & JQuery. I'm late to the Javascript jamboree of other frameworks, but I've been tinkering with Webpack and node (mainly using other dev's sources), but I've hesitated to leave Rails.  Is there a frontend (or full stack) that's thought to be "best" or most friendly to Solidity & Ethereum, or blockchain in general?  Of course I'd like to use a Rails backend if there is no real penalty for doing so. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look on [Drizzle](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started) (made by the [Truffle team](https://truffleframework.com/)).

Using Truffle (Solidity Smart Contract development framework), it makes simple to build React web application on top of Ethereum without struggling with web3js library.

The development flow is the following:

- Develop and test your Solidity smart contracts using [**Truffle**](https://truffleframework.com/)
- Deploy your Truffle project on a local testing blockchain with [**Ganache**](https://truffleframework.com/ganache) or on a public network (testnet, mainnet)
- Build your frontend application (interacting with your Smart Contract) using [**Drizzle**](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started)

More info: https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is that easy to find something friendly to solidity, but `javascript` frontend frameworks meant to deal with the ethereum nodes are the most developed. So taking javascript frameworks will help you more.

Besides javascript is very permissive on types and data formats so it I the best to deal with weird responses like those from the blockchain.